# Getting an error when casting float to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes, data-conversion

Moving data from flost to decimal(5,2).  largest value I could find int he existing data is 94.23 but when I try to cast to decimal it throws error.

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.
```

I tried copying straight over without casting, got that error.  So then I tried casting first:

```
     CAST(Purity as decimal(5,2))
```

Same error.

I noticed there are also nulls in there so I tried:

```
ISNULL(CAST(Purity as decimal(5,2)),0)
```

Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look for the largest value in the database?

```
select max(Purity)
from t;
```

And, in the event that `Purity` is really a string, you might have other things going on.  So, you can try:

```
select max(convert(purity, 18, 6))  -- or something like this
from t;
```

Comment: select max() found a value of 9845 (no decimal) so there is my issue.  Thanks.